# select bigger value's records in a query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For instance, I do

```
select * from tblClientInfo
with some condition
```

and there are 2 records:

```
 ClientID=001, Salary=500. 
 ClientID=001, Salary=550.
```

How Can I just select the record with the highest Salary? FYI, there might be more than 2 records as well.

I know how to asc sort but I don't know how to just select one of them.

This is my code

```
Select A.AgencyID,19,291,
BETAC.FirstName,BETAC.LastName,BETAC.Phone,BETAC.EMailAddress,BETAC.AnnualIncome,BETAC.Occupants,BETAC.Children2,
BETAC.Children5,ISNULL(BETAC.Children17, 0) ,BETAC.Elderlys,BETAC.Disableds,
0,0,TKFT.FuelTypeID,TKV1.LookupValueID,
BETAC.LandlordName,BETAC.LandlordAddress,BETAC.LandlordCity,BETAC.LandlordState,BETAC.LandlordZip,
BETAC.LandlordPhone,BETAC.HeatInRent,BETAC.DHWInRent,'2018/01/01',BETAC.FirstPrintedDate,
BETAC.StatusDate,NULL,NULL,ISNULL(BETAC.PovertyLevel,0),
BETAC.HighUse,BETAC.HighBurden,ISNULL(BETAC.Section8Housing,0),NULL,NULL,0,BETAC.IsRequestWNZ,
BETAC.SignatureConfirmation,BETAC.MoveInOut,CO.CountyID,
0,0,0,1,BETAC.BenefitAmount,0,1,U.UserID,BETAC.ClientNumber 

from LABeta_FA.dbo.tblClientInfo as BETAC
join LABeta_FA.dbo.tgAgency as BETAA on BETAA.AgencyID=BETAC.AgencyID
join tgAgency as A on BETAA.Phone COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=A.Phone COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
join LABeta_FA.dbo.tgClientStatus as LACS on LACS.ClientStatusID=BETAC.ClientStatusID
--join tlkpValues as TKV on TKV.DisplayName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=LACS.ClientStatus COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
join LABeta_FA.dbo.tlkpHeatingSource as LATKHS on LATKHS.HeatingID=BETAC.FuelTypeID
join tlkpFuelType as TKFT on TKFT.FuelType COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=LATKHS.HeatingSource COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
join LABeta_FA.dbo.tlkpBuildingType as TKBT on TKBT.BuildingTypeID=BETAC.BuildingTypeID
join tlkpValues as TKV1 on TKV1.DisplayName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=TKBT.BuildingType COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
join LABeta_FA.dbo.tgUser as LAU on LAU.UserID=BETAC.UserID
join tgUser as U on U.UserName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=LAU.UserName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
join LABeta_FA.dbo.tgCounty as LACO on LACO.CountyID=BETAC.CountyID
join tgCounty as CO on CO.County COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=LACO.County COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
where BETAC.LastDate>'01/01/2018' and
BETAC.FirstName='Brandon'
```

Then the result is like

```
brandon benefitamount=400 date=2018/01/01
brandon benefitamount=450 date=2019/01/01
```

I want the result to be the highest benefitamount one.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Or do you want an answer for standard SQL?

Comment: So do you want all columns? are just 2 columns? how you want handle ties? are more than one ClientID and you want the max of every one or just one client? Depending of what you want you can handle differently from simple solutions to more complex.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner both of you are correct, I want the record, but not just a value. I am using mssql, I just tried the max, and limit, it gives me this: is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Let me repeat, I only want the query's result to be one record, with ClientID, with the salary. If there is a tie, for instance if there are another column called date, use the latest date to solve the tie problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rownumber as sub-query:

row_number is a function that provides and ordered list as a result. The ordered list starts over based on the partition (clientID) and provides order based on order by (1st benefitamount desc and 2nd dte desc).

```
select *
from(
      select [all of your columns and they must have alias]
          , rn = Row_NUMBER() over (partition by ClientID Order by benefitamount desc, dte desc)
      from [your tables and joins]
   ) a
where a.rn=1 -- returns the ordered result from above
```

Comment: When I try to integrate this with my own part, there is an error marked on the last second a, says no column was specified  for column 12 of "a".  Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: All columns need a name in a subquery

Comment: sir can you explain a little bit more what you mean by need a name?

Comment: You used it above as second tie breaker.

Comment: Sir I tried it like exactly what you wrote, and it tells me Invalid column name 'dte'.

Comment: Change dte to whatever your column name is that is the 2nd sort value. Is it date?

Answer (score 1):

use `max()`

```
 select max(Salary) from tblClientInfo where ClientID=001
```

if you want to select all the column of table you can use subquery

```
 select * from tblClientInfo 
 where Salary=(select max(Salary) from tblClientInfo where ClientID=001
            ) and ClientID=001
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `ROW_Number()` like as bellow

```
;With cte as (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition by ClientID order by Salary DESC) as RN  from tblClientInfo
)
Select * from cte where RN=1
```

Comment: This is the method to get you all the columns for the record with the highest salary.

Comment: @KeithL well I think that is what OP want

Comment: @KeithL This one works, but there are two *, if I want to put some certain column, which one should I put in?

Comment: Would you please give me some guidance on how to use the cte? I am a little confused how to integrate in my code. @download dowload

Comment: @ZechengLi Google common table expression. This is a T-SQL thing. It can also be done as a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one:

```
Select * from tblClientInfo where ClientID=001 order by Salary desc limit 1
```

Comment: correct! But I think max() should be easier. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Zecheng Li: But `max` just gets you the maximum value. You, however, said you wanted the *records* with the maximum value. So just selecting `max` doesn't solve the problem. Anyway, Shadiqur's query doesn't either, because it selects only one of the records with the maximum value. And it only works in DBMS that support the `LIMIT` clause, e.g. MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `order by` and some method of fetching only one row.  In standard SQL, this would be:

```
select t.*
from t
where clientID = '001'
order by t.salary dec
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support `fetch first`.  In some you use `top (1)`.  In others, `limit`, or even more esoteric constructs.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a group by with max(Salary) and a subquery which will help you give whole record for each group

```
  Select * from table where 
    clientId,Salary    
    IN ( Select clientId, max(Salary) from 
     table 
    group by clientId)
```

Comment: If I have some else columns related to this, do you think it will avoid the " is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. " this problem?

Comment: No, it wont cause any issue as the group by is inside subquery and not in the outer query

Comment: and BETAC.ClientNumber,BETAC.BenefitAmount IN

(select BETAC.ClientNumber,max(BETAC.BenefitAmount)
  I wrote like this, and it tells me An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.